# Convert CSV files to ARFF file for Weka

Tags: csv, file, weka, arff

I have 64MB of CSV file format with 423,463 instances along with 42 attributes. I would like to model it with WEKA I tried to convert to ARFF with the help of WEKA itself but it could not convert.
I tried to convert in online with the help of this website http://slavnik.fe.uni-lj.si/markot/csv2arff/csv2arff.php?do=instructions  but it could not.

There for could anybody suggest me how could I convert my CSV file to ARFF files?

Comment: As I tried to import in MySQL via phpMyAdmin I tried you to provide with screen shot of it but it did not get attached but it displayed the messaged "Internal Server Problem" so it could not upload. Therefore could u please suggest me the way I could convert CSV files to ARFF to work with WEKA.?

Answer (score 0):

Importing the CSV file into WEKA and saving the data as an ARFF file should work. If the 64MB file is too big, and that is causing problems you could try to break up the file into smaller files or select a subset of the data for initial analysis.

Comment: Hi Sarina,Thank you for your comment. Now I am planning to split the original file and convert part by part. If you know any other software which could convert entire file at once you can even share to me.

Comment: Note that this does NOT work for supervised datasets (datasets with class labels). I'm not sure if Weka has this capacity yet and you may need to create a text crawling script...